# How do I prevent GetOpenFileName() from activating firewall?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to select a file with GetOpenFileName() then rename it, but when I run GetOpenFileName(), Norton Security says "Suspicious network activity has been detected". I don't want to disable Norton, I just want to know how to stop GetOpenFileName() from accessing the network. Also, why is the open file dialog accessing the network anyways?

Norton doesn't pop up when I set OFN_MULTISELECT and NOT! OFN_EXPLORER, but the old style dialog cannot access folders or files with a space in the name.

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;

ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ZeroMemory(Path, MAX_PATH);

ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrFilter = "All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0";
ofn.lpstrFile = Path;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
ofn.Flags = OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;

GetOpenFileName(&ofn);
```

Please do not tell be to do anything with Norton unless that is the only way to fix the problem. If anyone can help, thanks a lot.

Edit: OFN_NONETWORKBUTTON doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Seems to me like Norton Security is brain dead and triggers on things which it should not. Which is fairly standard for crap Windows "security" programs. Just disable/uninstall the crap and move on.

Comment: `GetOpenFileName` is probably entangled with `ShFileOperation` (the new FileOpen dialogue). The shell function is probably triggering something in the SMB stack in case you use a network path. Also see [SHFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationa)

Comment: GetOpenFileName may be contacting the network in order to populate the "Network" item in the navigation panel.

Comment: is there any way to prevent it without disabling firewall?

Comment: @jww don't you mean `IFileDialog` instead of `SHFileOperation()`?

Comment: @HappyRedMapleLeaf `GetOpenFileName()` has a `OFN_NONETWORKBUTTON` flag.

Comment: @Remy - Yeah, that could be it too. I have not actively targeted Windows platforms in several years.

Comment: It probably flags your app, not the action. Try signing the app with a trusted certificate. Most AV software (if not all) for Windows are totally useless anyway.

Comment: ```OFN_NONETWORKBUTTON``` does not fix the problem.

Comment: You can use [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=4865) to check if there is any network traffic when your application (process) call the GetOpenFileName() method.

Comment: `OFN_NONETWORKBUTTON` hides the "Network" button on the old-style Windows 3.1 dialog. The new-style dialog doesn't even have a "Network" button to hide.